# ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management Overwrites Graduated-Color Class Break

Tags: arcpy, symbology

My goal is to generate any number of MXD files with custom class-break-values using a consistent, pre-defined style.

For example, in ArcMap (10.2.2 and 10.3.1), I have an MXD with a graduated-color layer that has a single class-break-value symbol in it.  I want to update this layer's symbology from ArcPy using a .lyr file *without* affecting that class-break-value.

I can do this very easily from ArcMap: `TOC > Layer Properties > Symbology > Import > Select the .lyr file > "Just the symbols" option > OK`

Is there a way to mimick this from ArcPy?

### First Attempt

When I try the following code (using the same .lyr file as above), the TOC layer's style is updated correctly, but its class-break-value is overwritten by the class-break-value from the .lyr file:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
sourceLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(pathToLyrFile)    
destLayer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, existingLayerName)[0]
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(destLayer, sourceLayer)
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

### Second Attempt

`UpdateLayer` has a symbol-only option, but it also overwrites the class-break-value:

```
arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(dataFrame, destLayer, sourceLayer, True)
```

### Third Attempt

Originally, I tried importing the .lyr file into a *blank* MXD file after modifying the class-break-value, but when I change the value this way, the class-break's *symbol* is lost (and we are back to where we started):

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(pathToLyrFile)
layer.symbology.classBreakValues = [0, 50]
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(dataFrame, layer, 'TOP')
mxd.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by rewriting my script in ArcObjects by adding an `ILayerFile` to a blank `MapDocument` and then modifying its `IClassBreaksRenderer.Break[n]` values as needed (without losing the original symbol from the .lyr file).

If ArcObjects isn't an option for you and you know the class-break-values ahead of time, [Mike's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/177802/65677) will be the better option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have had better success replacing the data source on the layer than applying symbology to a new data set. Try saving your a copy of each of your class break options to a lyr file, add that lyr to your new map, then substitute the layer it is referencing using Layer.replaceDataSource. You can code the whole thing and reference a table of mxd's, lyr files and data source paths, then just let it crawl through the folder of mxd's. Assuming a limited number of class break options.

Comment: In my specific case, I won't know the class-break-values ahead of time, but your suggestion is a good option for anyone who does know them - thanks.